# Show Multiplication Tables with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a page with JavaScript that has a button saying "Multiplication Tables." When I click the button, the multiplication table of 5 will show up in the "p" tag with the id "tables." I want to use a for loop to calculate the tables. Nothing is happening when I click the button.

HTML:

```
<body>
<button type="button" id="multiplication" onclick="table()">Multiplication Tables</button>
<br/>
<p id="tables"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function table()
{
var button = document.getElementById('multiplication');

var showTables = '';
for (var i=1; i<12; i++) {
showTables += 5 + "*" + i +"="+5*i + '\n';
}
var p_tables = document.getElementById('tables').innerHTML = showTables;
}
table();
```

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mguwoL6v/)? The only things I'm done: replacing `\n` with `<br/>` and removing unnecessary `var p_tables = `.

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet by clicking run snippet button below, I think it's working fine

```js
function table()
{
var button = document.getElementById('multiplication');

var showTables = '';
for (var i=1; i<12; i++) {
showTables += 5 + "*" + i +"="+5*i + '\n';
}
var p_tables = document.getElementById('tables').innerHTML = showTables;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" id="multiplication" onclick="table()">Multiplication Tables</button>
<br/>
<p id="tables"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Your are missing html tag before body and there might be some problem with your javascript inclusion, Also don't run table() function after declaring it.

Place the script either in head tag or before closing the body. Remove table() function calling after declaring it.